# Conversion of types of objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, types, type-conversion

How to write a function on python that accepts two objects in input and gives on output minimal type which both of objects can be presented?

Example: we have two objects: `1` and `5.25`.We can't convert them both to `int` because then we will miss information about `5.25` that will be converted to `5`. We can convert them both to `float`: `1.0` and `5.25` and that is correct answer. Sure we can say that we can convert them both to `str`: `"1"`, `"5.25"`, but in our interpretation we suppose that `int < float < tuple < list < str` (of course we can't compare types of objects, but we suppose that to get an answer) and then `float` is the minimum available type that both objects can be converted to.

I tried something like:

```
def type_convertion(first, second):
    data_types = [int, float, tuple, list, str]
    times = {}
    for _type in data_types:
        times[_type] = 0
        try:
            if isinstance(_type(first), _type):
                times[_type] += 1
        except TypeError:
            del times[_type]
            continue
        try:
            if isinstance(_type(second), _type):
                times[_type] += 1
        except TypeError:
            del times[_type]
            continue
        return times.keys()
```

But when I compare `int` and `float` the answer is `int` but should be `float` and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: `isinstance(_type(x), _type)` is pretty pointless, either it raises an exception or it is `True`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 but how can I solve it then?

Comment: I think you should use `isinstance(x, _type)` instead, if you want to test if `x` is *already* of the given type, not if it can be converted to that type.

Comment: @mkrieger1 it doesn't work. I tried

Comment: Then you have another problem.

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "can be presented"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I well understand your question you want to get the minimum/best type that can match two variables.

I have updated your ranking order as follows `int < float < str < tuple < list`, but you can still keep your ranking if you prefer. So here is a function that takes several variables as arguments and returns the name of the minimum type that match these variables:

```
def type_convertion(*variables):
    data_types = {'int': 0, 'float': 1, 'str': 2, 'tuple': 3, 'list': 4} # types and their rankings
    minimum_type = [0, ''] # this list will contain the ranking and the name of the minimum type
    for variable in variables:
        variable_type = type(variable).__name__ # get the name of the variable type
        if variable_type not in data_types:
            # if the type is not reconized we can always convert it in str
            return 'str'
        if data_types[variable_type] > minimum_type[0]:
            # if the variable type is of higher rank from the previous one then change the minimum variable
            minimum_type = [data_types[variable_type], variable_type]
    return minimum_type[1]
```

The `*variables` allows you to give the function as much arguments as you want, so you are not limited to 2 variables.

To get the minimum type call the function like this:

```
>>> type_convertion('a', 10, 0.5)
'str'
```